# Algorithm for sorting questions that have been re-arranged, knowing new position and old position

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Say I have a bunch of question fields and users can rearrange them and send to the server the new position and old position of the question(s) that have had their position altered and the server will then use this data to update all the effected questions position/number value in the database. As stated I am only sending back the new position and old position of the question(s) that have been moved and not of those effected before or after it etc. So that calculation will have to be done at the server.

So lets say I have questions numbered.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

If I rearrange them as such

8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Then all values between the new position for (question 8), which is now 1 and old position (8) will need to be updated, with 1 - 7 getting a +1 and 8 being changed to 1. This is of course a simplified scenario, the questions can be rearranged to a much greater complexity where effected ranges will overlap and other ranges terminate within other ranges etc. So the required increments and decrements will be combined. Sounds like a fairly common scenario so if someone can put up an example, preferably in c# would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the answers above: Can you just add a 'position' property to the question object (independent of it's position in the list)? The user changes this property when they rearrange. Then you can just do a ListOfQuestions.OrderBy(q => q.Position)?

This just

Comment: I do have this "live/actual position" property. Notice that I had stated that I only wish to send to the server the data for the question(s) that have been directly moved and not those effected that come before or after the question that was moved. So if I have questions 1,2,3 and 3 is moved to position 1 and we get 3,1,2 I only want to send the data for question 3 back,which is Old Position: 3 , New Position 1 and not of the other questions effected by the move. This is as to save posting back a lot data

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you're trying to simply do random insertions and removals of a collection.

If that is the case, a `Linked List` is a good option for that.  A linked list essentially has a head node(first node) and each node has a `next` attribute, which references another list.

that way, if you want to remove a node you can just make that node's parent node point to that node's child, and if you want to insert a node you can do the reverse.

[c# has a built-in linked list class that you might want to check out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to:
1. Create your fixed size list/collection (Collection A)
2. Put the questions with modified positions on the new positions/index
3. Iterate through original question collection and placing the unmoved questions in the empty positions of the new collection (Collection A). Update question indexes based on their positions in the new collection.

Crude I know.

Comment: Yeah and when iterating through the original question collection it would be required to check if "Collection A" does not contain the question before adding it to "Collection A" and updating the questions index to the current count in the loop.